# Integers are to natural numbers as $p$-adic integers are to what?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, integers, p-adic-number-theory

In the construction of the integers at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer#Construction), the integers are constructed as differences of natural numbers, with positive, zero and negative dropping out naturally. Additionally, in the article for [negative numbers on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_number) references the [Grothendieck construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_group#Explicit_construction), which creates a group from a communative monoid.

I was wondering what is the analougous pre-cursor of the $p$-adic integers?

Comment: Why do you believe there is such a beast? Every commutative monoid gives rise to an abelian group via the Grothendieck construction, but that doesn't imply that every abelian group arises as the 'Grothendieck quotient' or some commutative monoid...

Comment: Look at the isomorphism $\varphi : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}_p$. Why don't you look at $\varphi(\mathbb{N})$ then take the Grothendieck quotient ? You'll get $\mathbb{Z}_p$ from this after defining the absolute value and the metric and taking the completion.

Comment: Compare: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/49990/the-p-adic-numbers-as-an-ordered-group

Comment: Even when Wikipedia is technically correct, it tends to be so poorly written that it often leaves students of mathematics more confused than before.

Comment: IMO wikipedia is impossible to understand for the $p$-adic numbers

Comment: @user195209 What is $\varphi$? For positive integers it is just expansion in base p. For negative integers it produces nonterminating padics. So $\varphi(\mathbb{N})=\mathbb{N}$? Is this correct?

Comment: So the answer is $\mathbb{Z}$ is to $\mathbb{N}$ as $\mathbb{Z_p}$ is to $\mathbb{N}$?

Answer (score 1):

If you'd settle for a dense subset of $\Bbb{Q}_p$, you could look at the $p$-adic numbers with expansions that terminate.  This should give you *positive* rational numbers whose denominators are a power of $p$.

Comment: Or a dense subset of $\mathbb{Z}_p$ for example (the $p$-adic integers corresponding to) $\mathbb{N}$